# Multiple remoteCommands in a dataList, but only one call

Tags: forms, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datalist

This one is tricky and I do not understand why it works like this:

```
<p:dataList var="item" value="#{recb.friends}" type="definition">
    <p:column>
        <h:form>
            <p:remoteCommand name="getTaste" process="@this" 
                         actionListener="#{item.calculateTaste( recb.username )}"
                         autoRun="true" oncomplete="poll.start()" />    
            <p:poll autoStart="false" update="@form" interval="1"
                widgetVar="poll" oncomplete="poll.stop()" />                    
        </h:form>
    </p:column>
</p:dataList>
```

So what I expect to happen is: for each `ITEM` it will call the `calculateTaste` method.
What happens is: there is only one call, just for the last item in the `dataList`.

I run out of ideas what is wrong. I added columns so the ID's are generated, still it's not working :(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to the cause of the problem, this construct generates multiple JS variables with exactly the same name `getTaste` in the same scope, basically like so:

```
<script>var getTaste = function() { ... }</script>
<script>var getTaste = function() { ... }</script>
<script>var getTaste = function() { ... }</script>
...
```

They're basically overriding each other in the order they're declared and when invoking `getTaste()` on DOM ready basically the last one would be actually invoked. This matches exactly the symtoms you're observing (looking in the generated HTML source yourself by rightclick, *View Source* in browser would also have told you that).

You'd like to give them each an unique JS variable name. You can make use of the `varStatus` attribute of the `<p:dataList>` to get the current iteration status with among others the `getIndex()` method.

```
<p:dataList ... varStatus="loop">
    ...
    <p:remoteCommand name="getTaste#{loop.index}" ... />
```

This way the generated code ends up with unique JS variable names:

```
<script>var getTaste0 = function() { ... }</script>
<script>var getTaste1 = function() { ... }</script>
<script>var getTaste2 = function() { ... }</script>
...
```

I'd also apply the same solution on `<p:poll widgetVar>` by the way.

```
<p:dataList ... varStatus="loop">
    ...
    <p:remoteCommand name="getTaste#{loop.index}" ...
        oncomplete="poll#{loop.index}.start()" /> 
    <p:poll ...
        widgetVar="poll#{loop.index}" oncomplete="poll#{loop.index}.stop()" />
```

Comment: Oh my god.. so blind. I was looking at the forms id's etc. And I even was correcting the p:remoeCommands name lately, but havent noticed what was generated in scripts! Thanks thanks so much!